# pipe ls to grep (lines vs. "items")

Tags: grep, pipe, ls

Consider the following command:

```
ls
dir1 dir2 file1
x1   x2   y2
```

when this output is piped into e.g. grep each file/directory is processed as an 'item'.

```
ls | grep f
file1
```

So obviously there is a distinction between the actual output that a `ls` produces and the input that is processed by grep.

Since grep operates on lines one could expect that `ls | grep f` would show the whole first line, namely: `dir1 dir2 file1`

What am I missing here? What is the mechanism behind this behavior?

Comment: It's all in the ([`ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html)) manual... _The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the `-C`, `-m`, or `-x` options is specified._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible for a command to detect when its output is going to a TTY or not. Thus in this particular case, when `ls` detects that its output is not going to a TTY, it behaves as if `-1` were passed as an argument.

You can see this, and that `grep` is not doing anything special by using `cat`:

```
ls | cat
```

Comment: alright, this makes sense. Does anybody know how e.g. a bash script could create an output switch for the cases two (tty and stdout)? Would be interesting to see this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But if you're asking how to detect whether output is going to a TTY in a shell script, use `if [ -t 1 ]; ...` or `if test -t 1; ...`

Comment: yes, this line was the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To see how `ls` behaves when its output is being redirected, you can try running

```
ls | cat
```

or

```
ls -1
```

which is how `ls` behaves when its output doesn't go to a TTY.

Comment: There is more difference like for terminal output option `-q` is set by default