# keep formatting when piping ls to head

Tags: shell-script, ls, head

when I call `ls` in `~` i get

```
Documents  Downloads  Templates  Desktop  Music  Videos  Public  Pictures
```

If i pipe `ls` to head (e.g. `ls | head -30`) i get

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
```

I am trying to alias `ls` to `ls | head -30` in order to not spam my terminal when doing `ls` in a big folder. The problem is that i prefer the first formatting (from normal `ls`).
Is there any way I can keep the original formatting while limiting the number of results?

Comment: Related: [pipe ls to grep (lines vs. "items")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295136/pipe-ls-to-grep-lines-vs-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [man page for ls](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) describes:

```
-C    list entries by columns
```

So,

```
alias ls='ls -C | head -30'
```

Beware that such an alias will preclude you from being able to pass any parameters to `ls`.  For example:

```
ls /tmp/
```

will likely not do what you expect.  You may find that a shell function is a better choice than an alias.

Comment: First of all tank you, your solution works perfectly :) Secondly, I have never written a shell function, do you by chance know if such a function already exists somewhere or where I could look for one?

Comment: @Telem There are numerous questions on Unix.StackExchange regarding that, many of them duplicates of each other.  [See this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29060/bash-alias-arguments) and its related and duplicate links.

Answer (score 2):

this works:

```
unbuffer ls | head
```

it tricks the ls command, to behave like it's writing to a terminal